# Compressing fonts for using in web

Tags: css, font-face, webfonts

Can fonts be compressed someway before using as webfonts? I have a font file which is 150kB. Is it possible to compress it down.

And also if i call for both font `.eot` and `.ttf` will both be downloaded by browsers?

Answer (score 16):

If you use the FontSquirrel @font-face kit generator -  https://www.fontsquirrel.com/tools/webfont-generator - and choose the expert setting, you can manipulate the settings to achieve a little better compression.

Comment: thanks! there is lots of font format. Can you tell which format i should use for all latest browser compatibility? Basically i know that `.eot` is for IE and `ttf` can be used for other browsers. If i include both font face in my css are browsers going to download both font formats?

Comment: When I design a site, I use `.eot`, `.ttf`, `.woff`, and `.svg`.  That pretty much covers everything.  `.svg` is for earlier iOS devices, so could be left off it you don't care about them.  `.woff` is the Web only format supported by the major new browsers (IE9, Chrome, FF).

Answer (score 1):

You can compress `.woff` font files with https://github.com/hn/woff-compress. It uses zlib's Z_BEST_COMPRESSION flag or Zopfli to **losslessly** shrink files down to a minimum.

If you want to **lossy** reduce files even more, you can remove unneeded glyphs from the font as discussed in [Way to reduce size of .ttf fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635423/way-to-reduce-size-of-ttf-fonts).

Comment: i got a error by runnong compress.pl ,WOFF TableDirectoryEntry 7 broken (length  mismatches 294832) at D:\woff-compres
s.pl line 139.  so how do i set the flag ?