# @font-face flash of unstyled text in internet explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer-9, font-face

I'm currently building an asp site with @font-face but I have encountered the dreaded Flash Of Unstyled Text bug in internet explorer 9. So far I have moved my scripts underneath my css files and used the [bullet proof syntax](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/further-hardening-of-the-bulletproof-syntax). As far as I can tell I have played by the rules but nothing seems to  fix this problem. My question is this: Is this bug avoidable or are all these methods merely damage control via getting the browser to download the fonts quicker? I realise there similar questions, but its important for me to know if im just fighting against internet explorer's natural inclination to load fall back fonts whilst it waits for the @font-face. Sadly, I cannot use google web fonts and I'd prefer not hide my content for a few seconds and reveal it with jQuery (not really a fix!).

For those who interested the size of my files are approx 33k.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**To prevent the FOUT in IE9, you can embed the TTF-Font-File in CSS via base64-encoding** 
(This solution works in all Browsers)

*Be shure to deliver EOT files to IE <=8*

```
<!--[if (lte IE 8) & (!IEMobile) ]>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="styles/fontface-ielte8.css" />
<![endif]-->
```

Put in your @font-face-rule ([fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) recommended)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MaidenDataURITest';
    src: url('MaidenOrange-webfont.eot');
    src: url('MaidenOrange-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

**Next step**, include the @font-face-declaration for all other browsers (IE9+ supports media-queries [more info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms530813(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="screen and (min-device-width: 1px)" href="styles/fontface.css" />
```

Put in your @font-face-rule with the TTF-file via DataURI(base64-encoding):

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'MaidenDataURITest';
    src: url('data:application/octet-stream;base64, [your-base64-data]') format('truetype');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}
```

Therefore use [fontsquirrel](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator) to generate the DataURI -> expert mode.
Nice to know: IE8 supports dataURI until 32KiB. IE9 doesn't have such limitation.

**DataURI Generator** for all types of files: [click here](http://t.larskl.de/dataurl)

**[live demo from above »](http://georgepantazis.com/demos/fontface-datauri/)**

---

To **improve the download-time**

**deliver just the characters you need** via unicode-range: http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#unicode-range-desc
This will cut down the download time and file-size that have to be download (works in IE9+ and newer Browsers, otherwise the whole font will be downloaded)

```
@font-face {
    font-family: foo;
    src: url('foo.woff');
    unicode-range: U+31-33;
}
```

And **the next step** you can **apply this to set expiration dates** for it via .htaccess on apache servers to let the Web-Browser know, he should cache the font-files:
This would leave the flash of unstyled content definitely on a revisit.

```
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    <FilesMatch "\.(eot|woff|ttf|svg)$>
        ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 years"
    </FilesMatch>
</IfModule>
```

And then **compress the font-files** for faster download (via .htaccess-file):

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE  application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/x-font-ttf image/svg+xml
```

WOFF-files have allready a gzip compression built in.

You can create a .htaccess-file on your server and write this properties into.
Works well on Apache-Servers :)

---

More details:

Live example: http://georgepantazis.com/demos/fontface-datauri/

Paul Irish about FOUT: http://paulirish.com/2009/fighting-the-font-face-fout/

Compatibility details and checklist: http://www.aaronpeters.nl/blog/IE9-performance-checklist

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, unfortunately Im on an IIS server. Do you know if I can still use your method?

Comment: The .htacces configuration not.. The IIS-Documentations-Page has a tutorial to turn it on: http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/25d2170b-09c0-45fd-8da4-898cf9a7d568.mspx?mfr=true .Otherwise, another possibility is to upload the font on fontsquirrel and edit it (expert mode) where you can make the font-file smaller: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6082336/compressing-fonts-for-using-in-web[link]

Comment: I managed to compress the files down to about 20k. My main question remains unanswered though - can this behaviour be limited or am I just forcing it to download before the user can see the font rendereing? I'll award you the answer if you can tell me that one thing :) Thanks!

Comment: The second one :) . I finally found the solution that covers your main question exactly. **To prevent the FOUT in IE9, you can embedding the WOFF-Font-File in CSS via base64-encoding**. So what does that mean? You can test an example here: http://georgepantazis.com/demos/fontface-datauri/ **To do so**: Upload your font on fontsquirrel again (expert mode) and choose Base64 Encode. Look at the example and try to set up your markup the same way. _Important details_: IE8 supports data URI until 32KiB IE9 doesn't have such limitation. WOFF for IE9 recommended. They have a gzip compression built in.

Comment: Thanks dude, much appreciated, you nailed it.

Comment: there is still FOUT in IE9 when looking at `http://georgepantazis.com/demos/fontface-datauri/`

Answer (score 1):

You can prevent the FOUT by placing your font declarations into a separate css file and placing an import to this file at the top of your css. This works because @import is blocking so it does affect performance.