# IE9 fonts not rendering

Tags: html, css, fonts, internet-explorer-9

I have checked the search, and found a multitude of resources, however none have worked.

Chrome, FF, IE7+8 all load in the font 'Gotham-Book' perfectly fine; however in IE 9 it just displays default browser.

In the css this is my @font-face

```
@font-face {
font-family: "Gotham-Book";
src: url('../Fonts/Gotham-Book.eot?') format('embedded-opentype'), 
     url('../Fonts/Gotham-Book.otf') format("opentype"),
     url('../Fonts/Gotham-Book.ttf')  format('truetype');
}
```

I got the ? in the url from [here](http://www.fontspring.com/blog/the-new-bulletproof-font-face-syntax/).

I added this to my httpd.conf (as suggested on stack)

```
<FilesMatch "\.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$">
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
    Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "http://localhost"
</IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

With no avail. Has anyone got any suggestions for IE 9?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IE9 is using font in woff format. Looks like you're not providing it.

Comment: I usually use http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator - it generates all required file formats for you.

Comment: Thank you, now in ie9 the default font loads, and then the new font loads - any advice?

Comment: Here is some suggestion on how to fix that:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836529/font-face-flash-of-unstyled-text-in-internet-explorer-9