# is there any tool to compress fonts file

Tags: html, css, svg, nginx, fonts

what i need

- i need to compress fonts file (from 500 kb ->200 kb).
- i have google & found nothing regrading this context.
- i have tried with nginx setting but its by default working .woff , but i want compression for .eof ,.ttf,.svg .
- as per our requirements we are not using google fonts i have read the google font forum and found fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=FontName&text=Lorem%20Ipsum  while using there fonts we could save file size.
- but i  need to compress .ttf, .eot,.svg fonts .
- is there any other way we could save fonts size.
- i have tried in .htacess file

  ```
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|public|\.txt)
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?$1

  <ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
  <ifmodule mod_mime.c>
  Addtype font/opentype .otf
  Addtype font/eot .eot
  Addtype font/truetype .ttf
  </ifmodule>
  AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain text/xml text/css   application/x-javascript application/javascript text/text font/opentype $
  </ifmodule>
  ```
- i have reffr link: [Way to reduce size of .ttf fonts?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2635423/way-to-reduce-size-of-ttf-fonts)
- i have download http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/downloads/gnulinux/ fontforge but i cannot compress fonts from this tool

Answer (score 0):

you can try to add the font mime-types to nginx gzip_types in your nginx config:

```
gzip            on;
gzip_types       application/vnd.ms-fontobject application/font-sfnt image/svg+xml application/font-woff;
```

you can do this on location server or http level...

The mime Types for the font files are:

- .woff (application/font-woff)
- .ttf   (application/font-ttf)
- .eot   (application/vnd.ms-fontobject)
- .otf   (application/font-otf)
- .svg  (image/svg+xml)

Comment: i have a few font files and im sorry to say that compressing `.woff`, `.woff2` or `.eot` doesn't do much tried with both gzip and brotli, at best it shrinks it by one or two kb. But `.ttf` compress well haven't tried `.otf` or `.svg` tho.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thanks for posting this out. You should not use server side compression for woff,  woff2 and eot as these are already compressed formats. https://gist.github.com/sergejmueller/cf6b4f2133bcb3e2f64a#good-to-know